# Insertion Sorted Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

So for a class of mine I need to write a linked list in C, which adds or deletes items as they are read from a file, and as they are inserted, they are placed in order via insertion sort. Each line in the file contains a name, followed by either a or d, which states whether to add or delete that name.

I understand the concept of linked lists, and have implemented them in Java before. For some reason I just can't get this to work in C. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The first value now makes it into the list, but there is another issue as commented below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char name[42];
    struct node *next;
};

void insertNode(char name[42], struct node *head)
{
    struct node *new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(new->name, name);

    struct node *curr = head;
    int finished = 0;

    if(!curr)
    {
         head = new;
         return;
    }

    while(curr->next != NULL) //This loop right here is not working
    //it doesn't make it into the loop, curr somehow equals null
    //not sure why this isn't working
    {
        if((strcmp(curr->name, new->name) < 0))
        {
                new->next = curr->next;
                curr->next = new;
                finished = 1;
                break;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(finished = 0)
    {
        new->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = new;
    }
}

void removeNode(char name[42], struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(temp->name, name);
    struct node *curr = head;

    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        if(curr->next == temp)
        {
            curr->next = temp->next;
            free(temp->name);
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void FREE(struct node *head)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp;

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}


void printList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *curr = head;

    printf("Linked list:\n");

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", curr->name);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input = fopen("hw7.data", "r");
    struct node *head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next = NULL;
    strcpy(head->name, "");

    char *tempText = NULL;
    char *tempName = NULL;
    char *tempOP = NULL;

    size_t lineLen;
    int i = 0;
    getline(&tempText, &lineLen, input);

    while(!feof(input))
    {

        tempName = strtok(tempText, " ");
        tempOP = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        if(i == 0)
        {
            strcpy(head->name, tempName);
            i = 1;
        }

        if(tempOP[0] == 'a')
        {
            insertNode(tempName, head);
        }
        else
        {
            removeNode(tempName, head);
        }

        getline(&tempText, &lineLen, input);
    }

    printList(head);
    fclose(input);
    FREE(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the data file:

```
Beverly a
Kathy a
Radell a
Gary a
Chuck a
David a
kari a
Tom a
Tanya a
Scott a
Beverly d
Brenda d
Kathy a
Gary a
WenChen a
Chuck a
Mike a
Emanuel a
Linda a
Bernie a
Hassan a
Brian a
Gary d
Kathy d
Gary a
Eunjin a
Kathy a
Brenda a
Jun a
Peanut a
Travis a
```

Comment: I could swear that I just saw a question almost identical to this a few hours ago.

Comment: You have a flaw in your `insertNode` function when you insert the very first node (i.e. when `head` is a null pointer). Search for and read about *emulating call by reference in c* to understand why and learn how to fix it.

Comment: `head = new;` does not change value of passed variable.

Comment: There are also many other flaws (like you comparing two pointers that will *never* be equal in `removeNode`). Please learn how to use a debugger, and how to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. That will help you find most (if not all) problems in the code.

Comment: Lastly, please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is for just a 200 level class, so bear with me here, I'm still learning. Would it be more appropriate to check if the end of file is reached, then break at the end of the while loop after the getline? We haven't gone over emulation of passing by reference, so that's new to me, and I don't imagine this assignment would require that; it would be pretty unfair for something that wasn't taught to be in an assignment. It's also a bit tough for me to visualize how to apply this here, but I'm going to look into it more.

Comment: For the loop and the reading, please [read the `getline` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and check what it returns. In other words, loop while `getline` doesn't return `-1`. As for the pass-by-reference, it might be something the teachers expects you to research yourself? Because without it you simply can not solve it the way you do. Remember that arguments in a function are *local variables*, and only exists in the scope of their functions. All changes to them will be lost once the function returns.

Comment: I am **positive** you did *not* intend *assignment* with this statement: `if (finished = 0)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right, boy do I need some sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a plethora of things wrong in this code, including, but not limited to:

- Incorrect out-parameter handling (ie. they're not out-parameters, but should be).
- Invoking `free` on data that was never directly `malloc`'d or `realloc`'d
- Incorrectly using `feof` in a while condition.
- Multiple problems with pointer walking.
- Assignment where comparison is required. Likely a typo, but critical, none-the-less.
- Potential buffer overflows

Reworking the code for each of these, start with the basics. To avoid buffer overflowing your structure `name` member, just use a dynamic allocation. You're already killing caching by using a linked list; may as well make sure it's 6-feet-under:

```
struct node
{
    char *name; /* will use strdup() for allocation */
    struct node *next;
};
```

Moving on, the insertion routine can walk the list using a pointer to pointer (and `main` passes us the `head` pointer *by address*) so we can modify it via dereference. This is critical, and missing in your code:

```
void insertNode(char const name[], struct node **head)
{
    printf("Adding: %s\n", name);

    while (*head && strcmp((*head)->name, name) < 0)
        head = &(*head)->next;

    struct node *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->name = strdup(name);
    p->next = *head;
    *head = p;
}
```

When it comes to removal, we can do the same thing, which has the added advantage of proper head pointer management, even in the case of a single node in the linked list, or even none at all:

```
void removeNode(char const name[], struct node **head)
{
    int cmp = 0;
    while (*head && (cmp = strcmp((*head)->name, name)) < 0)
        head = &(*head)->next;

    if (*head && (cmp == 0))
    {
        printf("Removing: %s\n", name);
        struct node *tmp = *head;
        *head = tmp->next;
        free(tmp->name); // note: freeing what we strdup()'d
        free(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not found: %s\n", name);
    }
}
```

Though not required for this case, I always advise using the same by-address pointer to pointer mechanics with the scorched-earth `freeList` ideology as well. It ensures you don't leave the caller with a dangling pointer they foolishly may try to dereference.

```
void freeList(struct node **head)
{
    while (*head)
    {
        struct node *tmp = *head;
        *head = tmp->next;
        free(tmp->name);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

When it comes to printing the list, walking it with a const pointer is trivial:

```
void printList(struct node const *head)
{
    printf("Linked list:\n");

    for (; head; head = head->next)
        printf("%s\n", head->name);
}
```

Finally, the heart of your program, `main`. Fixing the while-loop to only continue while line content is actually read, and properly freeing the final result from `getline` rather than letting it leak (not that it matter here, since the program will shortly exit, but good practice), we get:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("hw7.data", "r");
    if (!input)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file: ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct node *head = NULL;
    char *text = NULL;
    size_t lineLen = 0;

    while(getline(&text, &lineLen, input) > 0)
    {
        char *name = strtok(text, " ");
        char *op = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        if(*op == 'a')
        {
            insertNode(name, &head);
        }
        else if (*op == 'd')
        {
            removeNode(name, &head);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    free(text);

    printList(head);
    freeList(&head);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

The following is the output from your input, with the added instrumentation I put in `insertNode` and `removeNode` to let you know what is going on:

```
Adding: Beverly
Adding: Kathy
Adding: Radell
Adding: Gary
Adding: Chuck
Adding: David
Adding: kari
Adding: Tom
Adding: Tanya
Adding: Scott
Removing: Beverly
Not found: Brenda
Adding: Kathy
Adding: Gary
Adding: WenChen
Adding: Chuck
Adding: Mike
Adding: Emanuel
Adding: Linda
Adding: Bernie
Adding: Hassan
Adding: Brian
Removing: Gary
Removing: Kathy
Adding: Gary
Adding: Eunjin
Adding: Kathy
Adding: Brenda
Adding: Jun
Adding: Peanut
Adding: Travis
Linked list:
Bernie
Brenda
Brian
Chuck
Chuck
David
Emanuel
Eunjin
Gary
Gary
Hassan
Jun
Kathy
Kathy
Linda
Mike
Peanut
Radell
Scott
Tanya
Tom
Travis
WenChen
kari
```

**Summary**

There were plenty of things wrong. I addressed everything I could find above, and hopefully provided some concrete examples of linked-list management that you can use now and in the future.

I *strongly* advise you walk this code in a debugger and pay *very* close attention to the variables as they change. Load up your watch-list and see what each line does as you progress through the input items. Learning by debugging correctly functioning code can be a great learning technique, and worth the half-hour you should spend on it.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the in depth explanations and code samples. I'll definitely use these as a tool to improve on what I have written and continue to work on learning more about how to properly use C. Last semester we used Java to implement linked lists, that was much easier for me. I really appreciate this, I've been working on this for hours today and was to the point of just submitting it unfinished until I saw this response.